# How to set path to ojdbc in rhel 8

Tags: java, ojdbc, oracle19c, rhel8

I am using RHEL 8.3 . I have installed Oracle 19c.
How to set path for ojdbc so that I can connect a java program with the database?
Do I need to set path for Oracle 19c as well? If yes, than how to do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to connect to Oracle 19c database from java using JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

For Java applications the easiest setup would be to use maven. The Oracle JDBC driver is on Maven Central.
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html

If you don't want to use maven, you can locate the ojdbc8.jar under your $ORACLE_HOME. This jar needs to be included in the classpath.

Comment: That is what I am asking. How to locate? I am new in Linux (rhel 8). Please tell me the proper steps to locate